# Getting index of a node on click

Tags: javascript, html, yui

I'm trying get the index of a tab in YUI using `delegate` along with the `indexOf` method - specifically I want to remove a tab on the click of an image housed inside of an **li** element:

```
var tabView = new Y.TabView({
    srcNode: '#data-table'
});
...
//creating tabs
...
var removeTab = function(e) {
    var tabList = e.container.all('li'); //returns a list of the 'li' elements/tabs
    tab = tabView.indexOf(e.currentTarget);
    alert(tab); //returns -1 (node not found)   
    //tabView.remove(tab);         
}
Y.one('#data-table').delegate('click', removeTab, 'img');//on click of the img, launch removeTab
```

I don't believe YUI has a simpler way of doing this-most guides I've found are outdated or don't implement removing tabs the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the delegate handler is set on `img` element - so `e.currentTarget` will refer to an `<img>` element (that was clicked).

With `e.container.all('li')`, however, you retrieve the collection of `<li>` elements. No element in this collection, naturally, can be equal to `<img>`. That's why `indexOf` fails.

One possible solution is finding the `<li>` parent of `<img>` element first, then check its index:

```
var liClicked = e.currentTarget.ancestor('li');
var tabIndex  = tabList.indexOf(liClicked);
```

Comment: Thanks very much and for the explanation @raina77ow. I was able to keep 'li img' in my parameters on the delegate function, as I have an icon within my li element to trigger the event, rather than the 'li' itself.